# How to open new tab using selenium C#?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

Here is the code I have written But it is not working Any suggestion will be helpful

```
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Selenium Automation\");
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://thealivecard.com/");

   Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    action
        .KeyDown(Keys.Control)
        .SendKeys("t")
        .KeyUp(Keys.Control)
        .Build().Perform(); 

    Console.WriteLine("new tab");
```

Comment: You can use following stackoverflow link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: This might help you. It has other js and other ways also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use to open and switch to a new tab in C#:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.open();");
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

The sending of keys seems to not always work. Depends on the page your are on, the focus state of the browser. While the JavaScript `window.open` always seems to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot It worked